# Two vectors x and y. How do I point to the maximum element in y and pick its corresponding element in x?

Tags: matlab, vector, max

I have two vectors `x_values` and `y_values`, each of the same length but `y_values` is computed from the `x_values`. How can I take the maximum element in `y_values` and pick its corresponding element in `x_values`?

For example if the maximum element in `y_values` is `31`, the program should return its corresponding value in `x_values` as `5`. Here is my effort:

```
function maxValue = maximumValue()
x_values = -5:5;
y_values = [];

for i = x_values
    y = i^3 - 3*i^2 - 3*i - 4;
    y_values = [y_values, y];
end

for j = 1:length(y_values)
    if max(y_values(j))
    maxValue = x_values(j);
    end
end
```

end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>> x_values = -5:5;
>> y_values = x_values.^3 - 3 * x_values.^2 - 3 * x_values - 4;
>> [ymax, index_ymax] = max(y_values);
>> disp(x_values(index_ymax))
```

`.^` is an element-wise exponentiation.

`max()` can return two values. First one is the maximum value, and the second one is its corresponding index.

```
>> help max
max    Largest component.
    For vectors, max(X) is the largest element in X. For matrices,
    max(X) is a row vector containing the maximum element from each
    column. For N-D arrays, max(X) operates along the first
    non-singleton dimension.

    [Y,I] = max(X) returns the indices of the maximum values in vector I.
    If the values along the first non-singleton dimension contain more
    than one maximal element, the index of the first one is returned.
```

And my suggestion is more MATLAB-ish.

Comment: Thank you Jeon. Yes, I am more MATLAB-ishing